# XSLT How to move sibling before another

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to change the order of element inside XML:

```
<currentElementId>4</currentElementId>

<level value="1">
    <level value="2">
        Some text
    </level>
    <level value="3">
        Some text
    </level>
    <level value="4">
        Some text
    </level>
</level>
```

The result should be:

```
<currentElementId>4</currentElementId>

<level value="1">
    <level value="2">
        Some text
    </level>
    <level value="4">
        Some text
    </level>
    <level value="3">
        Some text
    </level>

</level>
```

The element of value="4" which is specified in currentElementId is moved before element  of value="3", the target element to move is always specified in currentElementId.

Best regards.

Comment: The rule is not quite clear: why is the specified element moved before value="3", but not before value="2"?

Comment: Lets say you have elements: 1, 2, 3, 4 and the target element to move is 4, I want to move it just **one** step in the order to the element before it, the result will be 1, 2, 4, 3 the number of elements is variable and could be more than 4 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must have a **well-formed input** with a single root element, for example:

```
<root>
    <currentElementId>c</currentElementId>
    <level value="1">
        <level value="a">Alpha</level>
        <level value="b">Bravo</level>
        <level value="c">Charlie</level>
        <level value="d">Delta</level>
    </level>
</root>
```

Then you can apply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level[following-sibling::level[1]/@value=/root/currentElementId]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::level[1]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level[@value=/root/currentElementId]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain the **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <currentElementId>c</currentElementId>
   <level value="1">
      <level value="a">Alpha</level>
      <level value="c">Charlie</level>
      <level value="b">Bravo</level>
      <level value="d">Delta</level>
   </level>
</root>
```

Note that we are assuming here that the selected element is not the first one.

Comment: Excellent answer, I appreciate your promptness, your answer was clear and the format was neat.